# Find $\sec\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ if $\sin\theta = -3/4$ and in Quadrant 4. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

I keep getting this flagged as wrong, but I'm not sure why

> Find $\sec\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ if $\sin\theta = -3/4$ and in Quadrant 4.

My result was:

$\sec\theta = -4\sqrt7/7$

$\tan\theta = 3\sqrt7/7$

What am I missing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you said what you have actually done. Otherwise we are just guessing at what you are missing - for each wrong answer $x$ there are lots of errors which lead to $x$...

Comment: You need to pay closer attention to the "Quadrant 4" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check the signs of your answers. The question states that the angle is in quadrant 4. Which trig functions are positive in quadrant 4 and which are negative?

Comment: Thanks! I checked the signed multiple times. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the answers you give in your question do not have the signs I would expect them to have for an angle in quadrant 4.

Comment: @DeanA The signs are indeed incorrect. Just note that $\cos$ takes positive values for angles in the fourth quadrant, and so we see immediately that $\sec = \frac{1}{\cos}$ is positive there also, so your answer for $\sec$ definitely has the wrong sign. From that, knowing that $\sin$ is negative in the fourth quadrant, it is also apparent that your answer for $\tan = \frac{\sin}{\cos}$ has the wrong sign.

Comment: To elaborate
Quadrant I--All trig functions are positive...
Quadrant II--Sin trig functions are positive...
Quadrant III--Tan trig functions are positive...
Quadrant IV--Cos trig functions are positive...

You have a negative cosine function and a positive tangent function for an angle in Quadrant IV.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sheesh, I drew everything in Quad three for some peculiar reason and it stuck in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since $sin\theta=\frac{–3}{5}$ it must lie in third quadrant or fourth quadrant and we know that $tan\theta=\frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$ and $sin\theta=\frac{perpendicular }{hypotenuse}$therefore $hypotenuse =5$ and $perpendicular =3$ and $base=4$ therefore $tan\theta=±\frac{3}{4}$ and $sec\theta=±\frac{5}{4}$tan will be positive in third quadrant and sec will be positive in fourth quadrant.